# classList.toggle problem with more than one element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to style a series of buttons so that when clicked they change to a different style and the text content also changes. It is working except that when I click the another button with the same class, the other button loses its classList toggle. It all works until I press the button on the next element, and would need them to work independently since they are being used to mark whether the book has been read or not.

```js
const readButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".book__read-button");

readButtons.forEach((readButton) => {
  let clickCount = 0;

  readButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    readButtons.forEach((f) =>
      f != e.target ? f.classList.remove("clicked") : ""
    );
    e.target.classList.toggle("clicked");

    clickCount += 1;

    if (clickCount % 2 == 0) {
      readButton.textContent = "Unread";
    } else {
      readButton.textContent = "Read";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.book__read-button.clicked {
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid var(--teal-200);
}
```

```html
<ul class="booklist">
  <li class="book">
    <span class="book__info">The Catcher in the Rye | J. D. Salinger | 277 Pages</span>
    <button class="book__read-button">Unread</button>
    <button type="button" class="book__delete-button">
            </button>
  </li>
  <li class="book">
    <span class="book__info">Maid | A.Sommer | 277 Pages</span>
    <button class="book__read-button">Unread</button>
    <button type="button" class="book__delete-button"></button>
  </li>
  <li class="book"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "losing its classList toggle". You have code there that iterates over all of the elements with "book__read-button" and removes the "clicked" class. If you don't want that to happen... don't do it :).

Comment: `f != e.target ? f.classList.remove("clicked") : ""` - That's not how the ternatory operator (`... ? ... : ...`) is supposed to be used (which should be obvious because you had to add a useless `""`). Just use a regular `if (f != e.target) { f.classList.remove(...) }` or `f != e.target && f.classList.remove(...)` (or get rid of it completely as it is not necessary to exclude the "clicked" element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign an eventListener to each button and trigger a function to handle the toggle classList and the button textContent, try this:

```js
const readButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".book__read-button");

readButtons.forEach(readButton => {
    readButton.addEventListener("click", e => bookReaded(e));
});

function bookReaded(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    event.target.classList.toggle('clicked');
    event.target.textContent = event.target.textContent == 'Unread' ? 'Read' : 'Unread';
}
```

```css
.book__read-button.clicked {
    background-color: green;
    border: 2px solid var(--teal-200);
}
```

```html
<ul class="booklist">
    <li class="book">
        <span class="book__info">The Catcher in the Rye | J. D. Salinger | 277 Pages</span>
        <button id="the-catcher" class="book__read-button">Unread</button>
    </li>
    <li class="book">
        <span class="book__info">Maid | A.Sommer | 277 Pages</span>
        <button id="maid" class="book__read-button">Unread</button>
    </li>
    <li class="book"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue completely, I am still learning as you can probably tell. this makes the code way cleaner as well.